# MySQL 5.7 issue with stored procedures and definers

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I am currently porting a Tomcat-based system currently running on a legacy server on Tomcat 6 and to make it future-proof with Tomcat 8.5 and 9 and also to faciliate its continued use by moving to a new server running either of the latter versions, I have begun studying the system's code and DB dumps (I am planning to migrate the DB dumps to MariaDB once the new server has been deployed and the system running on the new server is OK.)

On MySQL 5.6, it works fine albeit with some adjustments in the DB connection files (`.inc` files). But on MySQL 5.7, I have ran into a showstopper. Whenever I import the MySQL dump using phpMyAdmin on the MySQL 5.7 server, even if I had set the stored procedures' `DEFINER` as the user alone (i.e. without any backticks - example is `root`), phpMyAdmin still sets the stored procedures' definer as `'root'@'%'`.

Whenever I try to load the system's front page on a Tomcat installation connected to a MySQL 5.7 DB server, the SQL connection-dependent subpages fail to render. The error message on both subpages is as follows:

`Error in main java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist`

Did MySQL 5.7 make backward-incompatible changes regarding definers and stored procedures? What can I work around these changes in my DB dumps?

(Edit: I am currently doing local porting/testing and will only do the MariaDB migration once the new server is deployed and the changes as described here are approved.)